# Unidata File Manipulation with C#

Tags: c#, unidata

I have a windows server with Unidata running.
I need to write a C# program that will manipulate a file and save out.

The way I currently have to do it involves going into udt.  I have tried looking at just manipulating the file itself, but doubt it would save correctly.

To start:

D:\u2\ud73\demo

udt
It replies with:
Envision Initialized....type in password.

:AE VOC LOGIN....(make changes and then type FI to save out)

Question is there a way to manipulate the file with C# and save it without going into udt at all?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check out [U2 Toolkit for .NET/Uniobjects.net](http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/u2%20toolkit%20for%20.net/v2.2.1/u2clients_u2toolkituserguide_v221.pdf). I can't comment on the wisdom of changing the VOC this way, though.

Comment: Thanks!  I do have UniObjects, but like you; I don't know if you can get away with changing a VOC this way.

Comment: Depends on what you're editing in the VOC - it's unusual, but the VOC is just another database table, so as long as you don't destroy any important items in there (like "SORT", "SELECT" etc.) it won't hurt anything.  If you're storing a lot of data in the VOC and it's not sized right there will be performance problems.  I'll echo Mike - what are you trying to accomplish really?  Is VOC just an example for this question?

Comment: I do migrations and it would be nice if I could write something that would handle all the actions or at least most of them.  Changing the VOC LOGIN file is one, changing CONNECT_APP is another...I am trying to change IP addresses everywhere in Unidata that need to be changed.  Since this is not a one time thing, I'd like to write a short program do to it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like overkill, using C# to edit the VOC file.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Is there a reason you do not what to do this from the UniData ECL prompt?

Comment: This is to try to create an entire process.  Migrating from one server to another, etc.  There is a list of items that point to databases, ip addresses, etc.  If I can create a one-stop solution, it would be  used over and over.  This isn't a one time thing.